# Using functions inside environment and only here

Tags: r, scope, environment-variables

I have a little question about environment in R.
I have an environment (let's call it `my.env`) inside my `globalEnv` and I'd like to define a function that will only use the variables inside `my.env`, so I wont have to call them `fun(my.env$foo)` but just `fun(foo)`.

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: You can use `get` with `envir` specified to get the object from the `my.env`.  Please show a reproducible example so that others can understand why you can't use `my.env$foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want non-standard evaluation. That usually involves `substitute`.

```
my.env <- new.env()
my.env$a <- 1:5
my.env$b <- 2

fun <- function(x, y, env = my.env) {
  x <- eval(substitute(x), envir = env)
  y <- eval(substitute(y), envir = env)
  x^y
}

fun(a, b)
#[1]  1  4  9 16 25
```

But note how `eval` follows the search path (`get` does this too):

```
rm(b, envir = my.env)
ls(my.env)
#[1] "a"
b <- 3

fun(a, b)
#[1]   1   8  27  64 125

my.env$b <- 4

fun(a, b)
#[1]   1  16  81 256 625
```

If that is not acceptable, you could do this:

```
fun1 <- function(x, y, env = my.env) {
  x <- env[[as.character(substitute(x))]]
  y <- env[[as.character(substitute(y))]]
  stopifnot(!is.null(x), !is.null(y))
  x^y
}

fun1(a, b)
#[1]   1  16  81 256 625
rm(b, envir = my.env)
fun1(a, b)
#Error: !is.null(y) is not TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works perfectly, I used your 3rd method :) I'll see the doc for more informations about substitute, thank you